# Calculate the width using javascript and adjust the css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using javascript for calculation of width for `#red` and `#yellow` and css to design. The `html` is :

```
<div id="gray">
   <div id="red"></div>
   <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>

<style>
  #gray {
    width:100px;
  }
  #red {
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
  }
  #yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
  }
</style>
```

The width is calculated in percentage to fill the color for `#gray`. The display is proper till the sum of the width for `#red` and `#yellow` is less then or equal to `100%` as because i have considered the `div` `#gray` as `100% width`. If the sum exceeds 100% then the color bar appears in two lines. Can the width for `#gray` be calculated when the sum exceeds 100% such that the bar comes in one line along with may be dotted line as an indicator where `100% width` is exceeded. Please ask me if i am unclear with what i mean. Basically i want both `#yellow` and `#red` to be in same line and not one below other

**Edit :**

```
config.hourPerPercent=parseInt(data.totalspace)/100;
var futureNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.inuse));
var recNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.used));

config.Usage=futureNum.toFixed(2);              
config.Used=recNum.toFixed(2);

$('#red').css('width',config.Used+'%');         
$('#yellow').css('width',config.Usage+'%');
```

The width is changed dynamically with the change of data and calculated whenever there is any change in data. I have attached three images below which will make it easy to understand what i mean. For the first image as the sum of the width is greater then 100% the `#yellow` comes below `#red`. Green color background is the width of `#gray`. I want that when the sum of width increases 100% `#yellow` should not come below `#red` instead it should be like the second image with a visual indication may be dotted line at the point where 100% limit is crossed like the third image. Hope this helps to explain my problem.

[image: This is the situation when sum of the width of <code>#red</code> and <code>#yellow</code> is greater then 100%]

[image: This is when sum of the width 0f <code>#red</code> and <code>#yellow</code> is equal to 100%]

[image: Final output display]

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Also, a quick sketch showing examples of what it's meant to look like would be helpful, if possible

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated my code along with the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following way :

```
config.hourPerPercent=parseInt(data.totalspace)/100;
var futureNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.inuse));
var recNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.used));

config.Usage=futureNum.toFixed(2);              
config.Used=recNum.toFixed(2);

var rem=Math.round(100-(futureNum + recNum));
if(rem<0){
    $('#red').css('width',config.Used+'px');            
    $('#yellow').css('width',config.Usage+'px');
    $('#gray').css('width',(futureNum + recNum)+'px');
}else{
    $('#red').css('width',config.Used+'%');         
    $('#yellow').css('width',config.Usage+'%');
}
```

Any better suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="gray">
   <div id="red"></div>
   <div id="yellow"></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery will be `place it inside $(document).ready()`

```
var w_red=$("#red").outerWidth(true);
var w_yellow=$("#yellow").outerWidth(true);
$("#gray").width(w_red+w_yellow);
```

According to your **UPDATE**

```
config.hourPerPercent=parseInt(data.totalspace)/100;
var futureNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.inuse));
var recNum=new Number((1/config.hourPerPercent)*parseInt(data.used));

config.Usage=futureNum.toFixed(2);              
config.Used=recNum.toFixed(2);
var factor=1.0;
if( (config.Usage + config.Used)>100 )
{
 factor=(config.Usage + config.Used)/100;
 config.Usage= Math.round(config.Usage / factor);
 config.Used=100-config.Usage;
}


$('#red').css('width',config.Used+'%');         
$('#yellow').css('width',config.Usage+'%');
```

In this way there will be and error of +/-1. But it is much better.

Comment: You mean to say `config.Usage + config.Used` is more than 100. right?

Comment: Yes. In that case how to adjust the width and display like the third image

Comment: This method re-calculates the width of `#red` to `41.67%` and that of `#yellow` to `45%` whereas originally the width of `#red` was `58.33%` and that of `#yellow` was `48.33%` as per data. I dont want this width to change instead find a way to display the sum of `config.Usage + config.Used` extra width as the third image when it it more then 100. Hope am clear